# Duplicate songs in Apple Music after syncing

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-music

Yesterday I switched from a PC to a MBP. I've been using Apple Music since it came out. I synced my phone and today I noticed many songs are duplicated, or extra songs I have deleted before are back on my phone, but all of those songs are grayed out and unplayable. The only option I get when I tap on it is to add it to a playlist or delete the song.

I can still play all my original songs, but the broken songs take up a lot of screen space. How can I get rid of these songs without manually deleting them all?

Answer (score 1):

You can make iTunes detect duplicate songs by going to `View -> Show Duplicate items` and delete your duplicate songs from here.

If some of the songs you have haven't been downloaded for offline play, you can also click in `View -> Only Music Available Offline` to show only the songs that you've downloaded on your system.

Comment: That doesn't resolve the issue, because the duplicates are only viewable on the phone, not in iTunes. When the phone is plugged in, Apple Music copies on the computer are shown over the songs on the phone.